# GROUP_CONCAT returning single result

Tags: php, mysqli, group-concat

I have two tables I am trying to get results from: table in the Users table while table 2 is the education background table.

Let say **user A** has multiple schools he inserted into the education table. if I fetch details from education and join it to users table the record will return by the number of education details inserted by **user A**.

for instance, if I say `select * from users u left join education e on u.id=e.fid` it returns back the number of times his details appears in education table.

So, I decided to use the query this way:

```
SELECT j.dob,j.id,j.sname,j.fname, j.mname,j.gender,j.localg,j.stateng,j.phone,j.mails,j.confirm_no,j.edate, GROUP_CONCAT(e.qualification SEPARATOR ', '), GROUP_CONCAT(e.course SEPARATOR ', '), GROUP_CONCAT(e.years SEPARATOR ', ') FROM jobseeker j LEFT JOIN education e ON j.id=e.fid  WHERE j.training_approval_status=1 AND j.confirm_no LIKE 'A%'
```

but it only returned a single row. What am I doing wrong? Or in what better way can I get the results.

Comment: You're not actually grouping by anything. Aggregate functions such as GROUP_CONCAT groups all of the results into one result.

Comment: @aynber, could please point me to the right direction with an example?

Comment: @aynber, thanks. Done...